# Of which philosophy is this when these points stick together?

Tags: scientific-method, idealism

- God made the Big-bang
- God created Earth
- God created creatures on Earth
- God created laws of nature including biology and evolution
- There are creatures created by God: Adam, Eva, other humans, …
- There are creatures created by evolution

Of which philosophy is this when these points stick together?

Comment: Sounds a lot like creation science https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_science. But I am not sure if that qualifies as "philosophy" ... _or_ science, really.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a "God of the gaps" argument

Comment: There's some confusion here - you cannot say that God created the laws of nature (biology/evolution) and the cosmic inflation (big bang) **while also saying** that God created the earth, creatures on the earth, etc. *If you do* then you are equivocating on the word 'create'. You could say *God is responsible*, as in, ultimately responsible, I suppose, but this is different from the common sense usage of 'create'.

Comment: yeah, it does sound like Scientific Creationism

Comment: some mod closed my question, hm, im still thinking about this scientific idealism/scientific creationism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop before the last point, it's called *progressive evolution*:

> Progressive creationism (see for comparison intelligent design) is the pseudoscientific belief that God created new forms of life gradually over a period of hundreds of millions of years.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_creationism)

If you include the last point, it's the more generic *theistic evolution*:

> Theistic evolution, theistic evolutionism, or evolutionary creationism are views that regard religious teachings about God as compatible with modern scientific understanding about biological evolution.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theistic_evolution)

---

As an aside: although sometimes lumped together with what's called [*creation science*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_science), *theistic evolution* (as well as *progressive evolution*) are derided by proponents of both *naturalistic evolution* and what's known as *young-earth creation*:

- [Dawkins] dismissed ... theistic evolution as a superfluous attempt to "smuggle God in by the back door."
  [- pp 12-13, Ronald L Numbers, "Darwinism Comes to America"](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=drk3zykoEy4C&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=dawkins%20smuggle%20backdoor&source=bl&ots=FEMThPLgth&sig=TGMl-kVb3eQ9ViQeJ6mtr931P_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS1caw1dvUAhWFipQKHTL0BesQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=dawkins%20smuggle%20backdoor&f=false)
- In rejecting God’s right to lay down objective moral standards and by appealing to evolution, you are left with an unsolvable problem of evil. Theistic evolution is intellectually unsustainable.
  [- Joel Tay, creation.com](http://creation.com/theistic-evolution)

Comment: tks, it sounds the most like scientific creationism

Comment: @johnlowvale The issue with using the term 'scientific' to describe the position is that it doesn't help to distinguish itself from The the other positions. Evolutionists deem evolution to be scientific, and the better-informed 6-day Creationists defend that position on scientific grounds as well. Each end considers itself the foundation of modern science, historically-speaking.